# Optimization results from xpress do not follow the specified variable type

Tags: optimization, mixed-integer-programming, xpress-optimizer

I found some problems where the optimization result from xpress does not follow the specified variable type. I set vartype=xp.binary when I create the xpress variables, but some of the results have values such as 0.13333, 0.36667, 0.5.

I found that this was caused by one of the constraints. When I disabled most of the constraints, the values are all binary. Then, I enabled the constraint one by one and found one set of constraints that is causing the value to be non-binary.

Has anyone observed this before? Any suggestion on how to enforce the variable value to be binary?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe the model was integer infeasible. Check the solver log and make sure it said:"optimal".

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen, you are right, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For sake of completeness, expanding Erwin Kalvelagen's comment into an answer:
Fractional values for integer variables usually happen when the problem is infeasible.
After `solve()` returns, you need to check `attributes.mipstatus` to make sure you actually have a solution available (see also the potential values for the MIP status [here](https://www.fico.com/fico-xpress-optimization/docs/latest/solver/optimizer/HTML/MIPSTATUS.html)):

```
p = xp.problem()
...
p.solve()
print(p.getProbStatus(), p.getProbStatusString())
if p.attributes.mipstatus == xp.mip_solution or \
   p.attributes.mipstatus == xp.mip_optimal:
    print(p.getProbStatusString())
    print(p.getSolution())
else:
    print('No feasible solution', p.getProbStatusString())
```

Another way to get the problem status is function `p.getProbStatus()`.